# Symfony2, PagerFanta results

Tags: symfony, doctrine, pagerfanta

How can I take a result as an array from PagerFanta in Symfony2.1.1 ?

```
        $adapter = new \Pagerfanta\Adapter\DoctrineORMAdapter($query);
        $pager = new \Pagerfanta\Pagerfanta($adapter);
        $pager->setMaxPerPage(45);
        $data = $pager->getCurrentPageResults();
```

Results of `print_r($data);`

```
ArrayIterator Object
(
    [storage:ArrayIterator:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Trucking\MainBundle\Entity\Sparcs Object
                (
                    [id:Trucking\MainBundle\Entity\Sparcs:private] => 77940
                    [container:Trucking\MainBundle\Entity\Sparcs:private] => MEDUUUU
                    ...
                    ...
                    ...
```

I want to get results as `getQuery->getArrayResult();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I will Do the query

   ```
   $array = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
   ```
2. Use the ArrayAdapter

   ```
   $adapter = new ArrayAdapter($array);
   $pagerfanta = new Pagerfanta($adapter);
   ```

Comment: This will get the whole result set from the database, not just the current page!!!

Comment: Yes it will. Working on Query is optimal. But @Dezigo want an array.

Answer (score 0):

You must to set hydratation mode to Query from the adapter:

```
$adapter = new DoctrineORMAdapter($queryBuilder);
$adapter->getQuery()->setHydrationMode(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
$pager = new Pagerfanta($adapter);
```